# Errors produce converting to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I attempted to convert my project to the new version of swift by going into xcode -> edit -> convert to latest swift version.  I got the following errors upon attempting to convert:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

(null): could not read data from '/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/playgroundIOS/BaseballUI1/Test/TestTests/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

(null): could not read data from '/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/playgroundIOS/BaseballUI1/Test/TestUITests/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

I am confused, as I have no changed the location of my Info.plist file

Comment: Have you tried checking your Info.plist file location in the project Build Settings to make sure that it is at the right location and that the setting has not changed due to some reason or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select project target in the Project navigator and then click the Build Settings - All tab. In Packaging section check that the "Info.plist" path is set to the location it is residing in project structure. Then do a clean build.

If not try deleting your derived data and give a try with clean build with above steps.